# DoubleAnimation exception when animating grid width with DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to animate a grid's width upon a toggle button being checked. I've used a data trigger in the Grid's style element to do this, however, whenever it's triggered I get an error, stating:

> Cannot animate the 'Width' property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'

I'm pretty sure it is possible to animate the grid in the way I'm attempting, as I've gotten it to work using a click event. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

```
<Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" x:Name="MainGrid" >

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
                </Style.Setters>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CollapseIcon}" Value="True">

                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard >
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.200" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="16" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        </Grid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize man, I completely forgot to get back to this Friday and then saw your question again today. Anyway you're so close! Move your dependency property for Width to the object and you're all done! This tested just fine on my end. Cheers!

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>


            <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Background="Red"
              TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" x:Name="MainGrid" >

                <Grid.Resources>

                    <Style TargetType="Grid">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CollapseIcon}" Value="True">

                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard >
                                        <Storyboard >
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                                             From="300" To="16" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>


                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>

                </Grid.Resources>

            </Grid>


            <ToggleButton x:Name="CollapseIcon" Content="Magic!" Height="50" Width="50"/>

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

ADDENDUM: Forgot in a DoubleAnim you need to be explicit with both `To` AND `FROM` or it just returns NaN in the From by default. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, thanks for chiming in on this again. Unfortunately I tried moving the Width to the object before, though I tried it again, copying your code to be safe, and I'm still getting the same error. It must have something to do with what's inside of the grid. I'll post some more code, in case that helps.

Comment: Yea I would venture to guess there's another culprit somewhere, I just tried that on a fresh wpf proj and it worked just fine.

Comment: This is what the [entire control](https://gist.github.com/jekrch/222c108e9ff7c61c8aac) looks like

Comment: Whoa, haha yea I'll have to swing back to this in a bit brother. Got monday meetings and stuff to deal with first. Although there were a few things that popped out as red flags just from an initial peek. Will circle back soon as I have more than a minute to spare.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the pile of code. I've really been trying everything I can think of. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's strange, if I replace the storyboard with a simple `<Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>` it works just fine, albeit without the animation.

Comment: Oh? That kind of makes sense. Cool, set a From="300" on the doubleanimation. Sorry I haven't even gotten a chance to rummage through your stuff yet but I do get the alerts when you reply lol.

Comment: Gah, that's it! Thanks a ton, Chris. You've been a huge help.

Comment: Yea sorry man, I forgot about that part of a DoubleAnim with how you're doing it. It's returning NaN unless you make it explicit so the frames don't have any idea what the hell you're talking about when you say To=16 then it's basically saying to you "uhhhhh, to 16 from what man? infinity? I have no F'ing clue" is a layman explanation. You could also do `From="{Binding Width, RelativeSource=TemplatedParent}` or ancestor, or elementname or whatever you need if it ever becomes dynamic. I'll update the answer, glad you got sorted.

Comment: I'm sorry I just have one quick followup. When I try binding the from width to the parent's width, it gives me the error: `The TypeConverter for "RelativeSource" does not support converting from a string.` I tried referencing the parent by name via ElementName, but that didn't work.

Comment: swap width for actualwidth, sorry driving. :)